# Progress 4GL/Openedge Moving Integer using OCX

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, ocx

How to create a module with `OCX` that makes the `FILL-IN (INT)` move like a lottery. i tried searching the net on how to do it but no luck.

Comment: Do you need help with creating an actual OCX? And what does move like a lottery mean? You need to explain this better!

Comment: Yes i need help with creating an actual module.. in the module, there are 6 integers that will spin.. then from left to right, it will stop one at a time.. until we get the 6 digit number

Comment: That could be done without using an ocx but regardless of that: on stackoverflow it's customary to show some effort, so: what have you done so far?

Comment: Thats the thing. I cant think on how to accomplish the code.. for now, i have just the design.. 6 FILL-INS and a button to get a random 6 digit number. these numbers are equal to the employee-no.

Answer (score 1):

You are over-complicating it.  There is no need for an OCX or multiple fill-ins:

```
define variable r as integer no-undo.

define variable z as integer no-undo format "999999".

define variable k as integer no-undo.

do k = 6 to 1 by -1:

    etime( true ).
    do while etime < 1000: /* spend 1000ms on each random digit */

      r = random( 0, exp( 10, k ) - 1 ).
      display ( z + r ) @ z.

    end.

  z = z + ( random( 0, 9 ) * exp( 10, k - 1 )).
  display z.

  /* pause. */ /* handy for debugging... */

end.
```

Comment: Thanks tom. I also did my own approach.. select a random number to the 1000th time. after selecting the number, i created a procedure to display screen-value on the fill ins to match the selected number. that made my own roulette type fill in..